# How to implement object-detection in OpenCV? (Cognex VisionPro like object detection)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, cognex

I have worked on some project which use computer vision software like Cognex's VisionPro. I am really impressing the way how Cognex's VisionPro detecting an object on image.

Let me descript about how it work.
First, the master image is needed to be trained. In that training process VisionPro will extract some features of the train image.
Second, Every time we want to detect that object in another query image, query image features will be extracted, and compare with the features of the train image to get it's location and rotated angle.

## My question

Can we implement this method on opencv? Which algorithms could work in this case?

## What I have done

I did some research and I know that we have keypoints detection methods like SIFT, SURF, or ORB and there is FLANN for keypoints matching. I have tried to run some example (most on opencv official tutorial), but the result it's not really as good as I want (it's to bad). The keypoints matching not really match on rotated object and it's really hard to get the rotated angle on query image.

This image below can better help you understand Cognex VisionPro's object dection.
[image]

Comment: that method is probably patented. you won't find anything similar **for free** until the patent is expired. it's probably some kind of parts model. SOTA 10-20 years ago. -- I'd recommend some more literature review. maybe similar algorithms haven't been patented. I recently saw a similar question and someone recommended recent research that seems comparable. -- you can probably come close by doing feature matching + homography (or lower-dimensional transformation). check out `opencv/samples/python/find_obj.py`. SIFT and so on are designed to be rotation-invariant, so your claim rings false.

Comment: if you want useful answers, provide some data that can be experimented with... and **also** show the code you've tried, and the results from that, and why you don't like the results.

Comment: Sift/Surf need some textured regions with low local ambiguity. This is why it often fails on artificial or virtual objects, which are often symmetric or low textured. If shape matching is basically what you need you could think about how to get a chamfer matching working for different sizes and rotations.